# Can someone explain in simple terms the licence on Google “satellite” images?

Tags: google-maps, data, satellite, license

What can I and can I not do with the Google satellite images?

Comment: I voted to close this question because I do not believe that legal questions should be entertained on this site due to potential liability for both the site and the person answering.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions regarding licenses should be asked directly to the vendor

Answer (score 9):

[Using Google Maps, Google Earth and Street View](http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html) is pretty clear and simple

Comment: Explaining it would be too difficult.